# What does it mean by "message queue" in this link?

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-handling, dom-events

I was trying to understand what's an event loop in JavaScript. Came across Mozilla Developer Network's link about event loop.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/EventLoop

It mentions

> Queue
>
> A JavaScript runtime contains a message queue, which is a list of
> messages to be processed. To each message is associated a function.
> When the stack is empty, a message is taken out of the queue and
> processed. The processing consists of calling the associated function
> (and thus creating an initial stack frame). The message processing
> ends when the stack becomes empty again.

What does it mean message queue in this context? Is it referring to every click or keyboard event we perform in browser? Each of this event is a message and added to queue?

Please clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term "message queue" means pretty much what it sounds like. It's a *queue* of messages to process (read: event callbacks to execute), one at a time and in order.

This "message queue" is *not* part of ECMAScript, but is rather used to *describe the behavior of processing asynchronous events in a single-threaded execution model* - every browser event (clicks, timers, AJAX, etc) is added to the queue and processed in the same manner. Similarly, node.js uses events for asynchronous I/O operations.

The "message queue" is processed until is *empty* (by the "event loop") whenever there is no JavaScript executing for the given global context (i.e. window or process). This is why blocking JavaScript is bad - it will *prevent* the queue from being processed (which prevents event callbacks from being performed) until the blocking code stops executing.

The [event queue / event loop in node.js](http://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-event-loop/) works the same way as a browser, just with different events. This is how node.js can support concurrency without exposing multiple threads and the associated complexity.

---

One of the most common ways fro code to *add* messages to this "message queue" is with `setTimeout` - the callback is added to the queue *when* the timeout expires. Assuming a little white-lie (as the callbacks are only added to the queue *when* the event actually occurs), consider that

```
setTimeout(f, 0)
setTimeout(g, 0)
```

will "queue" the callbacks in the sequence `f, g` while

```
setTimeout(f, 20) // MUST exceed time to g event firing
setTimeout(g, 0)
```

will "queue" the callback sequence `g, f`. These sequence guarantees can be relied upon because (of the setTimeout guarantees and that) the messages/events added to the queue are processed in order.

Since the code above is running (e.g. JavaScript is being executed) it is also guaranteed that neither the `f` nor the `g` callbacks will be invoked before the given JavaScript stops executing and the "message queue" can be processed. However, there is no general guarantee that (in either case) an additional event/callback is not processed between `f` and `g`.

Answer (score 2):

Each Javascript instance has an event queue (or message queue). A node.js instance has one, a browser has one per window (and possibly extension, etc, but you get the idea). The key thing to note is they are independent. While every click, keyboard event, etc, will be posting to your browser's javascript queue, it wouldn't have any impact on your node instance's queue (unless of course you wrote event handlers in your browser that were proxying these events back to node, but that would sort of be a strange case). Hopefully that helps to clarify. Let me know if I misunderstood your question.

You might find this link I found via a Bing search for "visualizing the javascript event loop" helpful in broadly understanding the event queue and event loop concepts, particularly if you check some of the further suggested readings various comments provide: http://blog.carbonfive.com/2013/10/27/the-javascript-event-loop-explained/

Comment: thanks for your quick response. i'm having pretty hard time understanding concepts of event loop and node.js. Can you explain the same without using node.js?

Comment: @SandyR I see someone else has answered the question with a bit more detail and it is an accurate explanation. Feel free to comment back if you'd like another take on it. I am also adding a link to my answer which you might find helpful.